# String from DB is not parsing in Powershell

Tags: powershell, formatting

While fetching data from db, I am getting a string which is not getting formatted in pwoershell.

String

```
[{"varun":"\\","rocks":true}]
```

It throws below exception
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: That looks like JSON.  I'm assuming you're passing this to `Convert-FromJson`.  Can you show us relevant part the script which give the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're using it with the `-f` operator as format string? In this case you'll have to escape `{` and `}` as `{{` and `}}` respectively because those are used for placeholders in the format string (e.g. `{0}`).

Also please provide more details next time, such as the complete error message (it says where it occurs, for example) and the code where it happens.

Comment: Thanks Joey for help, I'll make sure to provide more info from next time.